# Minimum Chrome version for TWA - options?

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, google-play-console, android-browser, trusted-web-activity

I have a [Trusted Web Activity](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/trusted-web-activity/) app that is displaying a Progressive Web Application by using the [Android Browser Helper](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/trusted-web-activity/android-browser-helper-migration/). The documentation and code indicates that the mobile app only runs properly when the Chrome Browser is 72 or above. The address bar is visible when the Chrome Browser is outdated. I believe I have the option of a Webview-fallback but I prefer not to use Webview as some of the app's functionality is incompatible with Webview.

While testing, when the Chrome Browser is updated on the same device, the trusted web activity runs without any issues.

What options do I have where the address bar isn't visible?

Is the min SDK the only way to set the minimum browser requirements or can I explicitly set a min Chrome Browser version in the Play Console for the app before the user downloads it? (which prompts the user to update the browser before installation)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to set a browser version requirement on the Play Console.

Besides falling back to a WebView, or showing the application with the URL bar, the other solution would to block the application from loading and ask the user to update / install a browser that supports Trusted Web Activity.